# Messaging the Model in my MVC

Tags: iphone, objective-c

To preface, I'm very new to Obj-C but I do have some OOP experience in C++ and Java.

So I've started reading and learning Obj-C for iphone dev, and now I'm attempting to make my very first MVC program.

Basically what I've done is create a button, and now I want my controller to message my model upon pressing the button. I've verified the controller method is successfully being called but im unable to successfully message my model from the controller. I don't know why but the function `(void)myfunction` isn't executing.

My controller is called `TestViewController`, and my model is called `Brain`.

```
//TestViewController.m
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestViewController

- (Brain *)mybrain
{
    if (!mybrain)mybrain = [[Brain alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"mybrain is initialized..");
    return mybrain;
}


- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Controller has been messaged!");
    [mybrain myfunction];
}


//Brain.m
#import "Brain.h"
@implementation Brain

-(void)myfunction
{
    NSLog(@"Model has been messaged!");
    return;
}

@end
```

Comment: You mean you're seeing "Controller has been messaged!" in your logs but not "Model has been messaged!"? Or are you seeing neither message?

Comment: Where is (Brain*)mybrain getting called?

Comment: I see "Controller has been messaged!", but not "Model has been messaged!" in my logs.

Comment: In this program, (Brain*)mybrain is not being called.

Comment: You mean you are not initializing mybrain and yet calling [mybrain myfunction] or just that the above code does not have the mybrain initialization part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you retaining the myBrain object? it looks like this code is incomplete. the first thing I see in the code sample as it is at the moment is that there is no retaining of the myBrain object anywhere. So its very possible its leaking and you are messaging nil and thus nothing happens.

Comment: Seems I forgot to create the myBrain object itself by calling -(Brain*)mybrain. I was indeed messaging nil.

Thanks.